# How to display a notification in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to display a notification using [Easy Notification](http://cssglobe.com/post/9537/jquery-plugin-easy-notification), but I don't want it to be displayed every time the page is loaded, but when it only has something to show

```
Try
  mailClient.Send(mail)
  ' ........      
  ' "message" is the hidden field that stores the string message to display
  message.Value = "Message sent."

Catch ex As Exception     
  message.Value = ex.Message
End Try
```

If the value of the hidden field is different from empty string, display the message it has , otherwise display nothing

```
<script type="text/jscript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($("[id$=_message]").val()!=""){
  $.easyNotification({
        text: $("[id$=_message]").val()
      }
      );    
     //Set hidden field's value to empty string 
     $("[id$=_message]").val()="";
    }
  
});
```

As you can see, I'm not clear on how to get/set the value of the hidden field

**EDIT**-----

I tried using smokesignals.

1. Added the dll to the bin folder
2. Put a placeholder control called plhMessages on my page and
3. called SendMessage from the load event of my page,but nothing happens. :(  Am I missing something???

ASP.Net

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhMessages" runat="server">
            </asp:PlaceHolder>                
        </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub btnSend_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Load
    SendMessage(MessageType.Error, "This is an error message set from the aspx page.", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: that's a bug, I'll fix it quick and shoot you an update.

Comment: updated: https://github.com/downloads/jonezy/smokesignals/smokesignals.dll

Comment: thanks :D, it does work now!!!  - I don't know how to thank you enough :D

Comment: your very welcome!  just lemme know if you run into any problem or have any features that you would like to see!  (also could you send me a link to it in use? If the site is publicly available of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your using .net I've got a library that I use for displaying messages, [smokesignals@github](https://github.com/jonezy/smokesignals), really simple and straight forward.

Comment: I love it,but how do I install it ? and what about if the users want to close the notification once they read it??

Comment: just add a reference to the dll, put a placeholder control called plhMessages on your page and call this.SendMessage from a page, control or master page

Comment: closing is something that i've got on the list to add in there, your more than welcome to fork the project and do it yourself?

Comment: I added a close button to the messages, you can grab the dll here:https://github.com/downloads/jonezy/smokesignals/smokesignals.dll

Answer (score 4):

If you had in the page a hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_message" value="Some text"/>
```

Then I assume the following should work:

```
$(function()
{
   var field = $('#_message');
   if(field.val() !== '')
   {
      $.easyNotification({text: field.val()}); 
   }

});
```

Probably you want to read:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I tried this : var field=$("#<%=message.ClientID%>");  and it works wonders